# HTML valid way of tracking outbound links via Google Analytics?

Tags: html, google-analytics

I am using [this](http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55527), and I have it tracking an outbound link, but I want my page to be valid.

This is the error I am getting: There is no "OnCick" attribute

The HTML is:

```
<p>View some of our student produced videos 
on <a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/johndoe" onClick="javascript: pageTracker._trackPageview('/outgoing/youtube.com/user/johndoe');" rel="external">YouTube!</a></p>
```

I added this to my javascript embed file, to track all outgoing links:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[href^=http]:not("[href*=://' + document.domain + ']")').click(function() {
        pageTracker._trackPageview('/out/'+$(this).attr("href"));
    });
});
```

So now my js embed file looks like this below. I notice I call $(document).ready(function() { at the beginning of both snippets, should they both go into one?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // opens links into separate window
    $('A[rel="external"]').click( function() {
        window.open( $(this).attr('href') );
        return false;
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[href^=http]:not("[href*=://' + document.domain + ']")').click(function() {
        pageTracker._trackPageview('/out/'+$(this).attr("href"));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are using some highly obscure or ancient version of HTML,  you are probably using XHTML, which is case sensitive and all lower-case. Change it to `onclick`.

Answer (score 4):

Use an [event listener](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html) to handle the onclick.

Answer (score 0):

As gms8994 implied, attach click event handlers to the links you want to track, on the `load` event of `window`.

If you don't want to do that, change the page's document type declaration to point to the Transitional XHTML DTD and use "onclick" (all lower case).

Comment: onClick is invalid in XHTML 1.0 Transitional

Comment: I should have added that the attribute must be lower-case, i.e. "onclick" is good, "onClick" is invalid.